# Windows 2008 fax with FAXCOMEXLib issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services, fax, winfax

I am using FAXCOMEXLib to implement a fax service.

I create a windows service, retrieve the fax document from database, connect to fax server. everything is fine, but when I open Windows Fax and Scan. The fax job is not int the outbox queue. But if I send out with WinForm program, the job will appear in the outbox queue so that I can cancel it or remove it.

```
    FaxOutgoingQueue outgoingQueues;
    IFaxOutgoingJob outgoingJobs;
    outgoingQueues = fServer.Folders.OutgoingQueue;
    outgoingQueues.Refresh();
    outgoingJobs = outgoingQueues.GetJob(severJobID);
    outgoingJobs.Cancel();
```

Comment: Hi Sheikh, I just want to know why the job didnot appear in the outbox queue when I send out with window service,

Comment: Is fax going from ur windows service?

Comment: yes.. when going from the windows service, the fax job was not appear in the outbox. any idea about this issue? thanks.